# Run Two Sql Server Agent Jobs in Parallel and Run a Third Job at the end of both

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-job

I have two SSIS ETL packages that I need to schedule to run on a daily basis. The two packages load data into two different staging databases so these can be run in parallel. However, at the end of execution of both the jobs, I need to call a separate job (stored procs) to load data into final database from the staging database.

Does SQL Server Job Scheduling Agent provide any features for tracking if the previous two jobs were completed successfully or not?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with the below answers. This is one thing SSIS is good at and SQL Agent is not. You _can_ put logic in job steps to inspect SSIS logs and SQL Agent logs for completion but this is very unreliable.

Comment: This is definitely a good option but I have only one concern with this. If one of the first two packages fail for some reason, I would have to restart both packages from beginning. I was hoping that if only one of the packages ran successfully, I wouldn't need to run other package if I kept them separately.

Comment: They are already seperate packages so there are any number of mechanisms to manage this. For example an environment variable that selectively disables one of the packages in your control package.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to Wrap your 2 SSIS packages in a Master Package - These can be run in parallel within this.
Then create a Job with this as step 1
Step 2 can be Exec sp_run_job [job you need to run]

Comment: This is also similar to previous answer and my concern is still the same. "This is definitely a good option but I have only one concern with this. If one of the first two packages fail for some reason, I would have to restart both packages from beginning. I was hoping that if only one of the packages ran successfully, I wouldn't need to run other package if I kept them separately."

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you include a third 'control' package in your ssis project that contains `Execute Package` tasks to run the two packages in parallel within a `Sequence Container`, and then an `Execute SQL` task following the successful completion of the `Sequence Container` to kick off the stored procedure once these both complete.

Doing this, you only need to have one Agent job that runs the 'control' package.

Comment: This is definitely a good option but I have only one concern with this. If one of the first two packages fail for some reason, I would have to restart both packages from beginning. I was hoping that if only one of the packages ran successfully, I wouldn't need to run other package if I kept them separately.

Comment: If you are wanting this to run on an unattended basis and can't abide double executions, I would recommend using a logging table to record the successful executions of your packages and putting a check in the control package on whether to execute or skip the package execution based on this log table.

Comment: That would be my recommendation too. I'd also query whether or not this is a valid concern as failures should not occur regularly. If you are worried about bad data from source files then use the error redirect to a quarantine table and keep going!